# Bad Breath Problem

Tags: brushing-teeth, gums, gingivitis, smell, halitosis-bad-breath

I saw a similar question like this on here but I don't think there was a solid answer. I have a terrible problem where I have bad breath all day especially in the morning but I don't know how to stop it. I am 17. I already:

- Have regularly brushed my teeth twice a day since I was 14 (before that too of course but not always regularly)
- Have never smoked anything
- I don't drink
- Just got my teeth cleaned at dentist (not surface clean but deep) and I was at the recommended plaque index level
- My diet is very healthy, I almost never eat out or eat junk food

I may be a little dehydrated during the day because I sometimes only drink 4 or 5 cups of water in a day but I tried drinking more than 8 at even spaced intervals one day and it didn't help, I just had to use the bathroom more.

I am really desperate to get rid of this problem. Sometimes when I floss a little blood appears but not much. Could I have gum disease? Could anybody advise what there is left to do?

Answer (score 1):

The first question I would ask in response to your question on gum disease is "Have you spoken with your dentist about the health of your gums?"

Looking at the [NHS webpage on Halitosis](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Bad-breath/Pages/Causes.aspx), it sounds that most of the possibilities have been ruled out, but not oral hygiene completely.

> The most common cause of bad breath is poor oral hygiene. Bacteria that build up on your teeth – particularly between them – as well as your tongue and gums, can produce unpleasant-smelling gases. These bacteria are also responsible for gum disease and tooth decay.
>
> If you don't floss and brush your teeth regularly, any food trapped between your teeth will be broken down by the bacteria and may be responsible for bad breath.
>
> Bacteria can also live on the rough surface of your tongue. **As well as brushing your teeth, cleaning your tongue can also help control bad breath**.

Although you eat healthily, food and drink could still have a role in the problem

> Eating strongly flavoured foods, such as garlic, onions and spices, is likely to make your breath smell. Strong-smelling drinks, such as coffee and alcohol, can also cause bad breath.
>
> Bad breath caused by food and drink is usually temporary. It can be avoided by not eating or drinking these types of food and drink too often.

There are other possibilities which you can find out by going to the webpage and going through them.